# A toy implementation of binary tree

Tags: c, binary-tree

I'm playing around with a toy implementation of binary trees in C.

I have a `typedef`'d struct `BTree` like so —

```
typedef struct BTree {
    struct BTree* left;
    void* value;
    struct BTree* right;
} BTree;
```

I have three functions implemented so far —

`BTree* genRandomTree(int depth)` — Creates a balanced binary tree of `depth` height and fills it with random integers

`int height(BTree* tree)` - Calculates the height of the binary tree

`bool isAVLBalanced(BTree* tree)` - Checks if a given tree is AVL balanced

I have run some basic test cases and everything seems to be in working order.

I am specifically looking for advice about performance and correctness regarding any edge-cases I've failed to take into consideration. I am **especially** interested in any method of converting the three functions into tail-recursive form.

I am specifically **not** looking for advice telling me not to use gcc's nested function extension (exploring this extension was part of my motivation for writing this program in the first place) or advice about not-having free'd memory. I am also aware that the recursion-heavy style I have written this in is **very** unidiomatic and recommended against, however, having fun with recursion was **also** one of my motivations for writing this program, so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wc++-compat` gives no errors or warnings. Adding `-Wpedantic` to the compiler options produces errors about nested functions not being ISO C compliant but nothing else.

Here is the full code —

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct BTree {
    struct BTree* left;
    void* value;
    struct BTree* right;
}BTree;

// generates balanced binary tree of maxDepth depth and fills it with integers
BTree* genRandomTree(int depth) {
    BTree* _genRandomTree(int curDepth, int maxDepth) {
        if (curDepth == maxDepth) {return NULL;}

        BTree* node = (BTree*)malloc(sizeof(BTree));

        node->left = _genRandomTree(curDepth+1, maxDepth);
        node->right = _genRandomTree(curDepth+1, maxDepth);

        node->value = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *((int *) node->value) = rand()%100;

        return node;
    }
    return _genRandomTree(0, depth);
}

// Calculates height of tree
int height(BTree* tree) {
    int _height(BTree* tree, int curHeight) {
        if (!tree) { return curHeight; }
        int leftHeight = _height(tree->left, curHeight+1);
        int rightHeight = _height(tree->right, curHeight+1);
        return leftHeight > rightHeight ? leftHeight : rightHeight;
    }
    return _height(tree, 0);
}

// Checks if tree is AVL balanced
bool isAVLBalanced(BTree* tree) {
    if (!tree) { return true; } // Null tree is trivially balanced
    int heightDiff = height(tree->left) - height(tree->right);
    int heightDiffAbs = heightDiff < 0 ? heightDiff * -1 : heightDiff;
    return
        heightDiffAbs <= 1
        &&
        isAVLBalanced(tree->left)
        &&
        isAVLBalanced(tree->right);
}

int main() {
    srand(6);
    BTree* root = genRandomTree(3);
    if (isAVLBalanced(root)) { printf("Balanced\n"); }
    else { printf("Unbalanced\n"); }
    return 0;
}

/*

Tree created by genRandomTree() after srand(6)

       86
      /  \
     /    \
   12      85
   /\      /\
  /  \    /  \
41   85  65   8

*/
```

Comment: ([B-tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) is why *BST* is a somewhat common acronym where BT isn't.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **Nested functions** are not in the C standard. It is a GCC extension, of a dubious value. Don't do it.
- **Casting `malloc`** is a bad practice. First, it is not necessary, and second, it may lead to a hard-to-find bugs.

  Along the same line, prefer `sizeof value` rather than `sizeof (type)`, e.g.

  ```
    BTree* node = malloc(sizeof *node);
  ```

  Among other benefits, this avoids double maintenance.
- <strike>**`isAVLBalanced`** seems buggy. It only tests the heights of immediate subtrees of the root. You also need the subtrees themselves to be AVL balanced - i.e. it also needs to be recursive.</strike>
- **Stylistically**, `*` shall gravitate to a variable, not to the type. Prefer

  ```
    struct BTree *left;
  ```

  Disclaimer: this is a matter of an (heretical) opinion. You don't want to say that `left` is a pointer to `BTree`. You want to say that `*left` in an expression yields a `BTree` object.

Comment: I'm curious how `isAVLBalanced` only tests the height of immediate subtrees, won't the two `isAVLBalanced` calls in the `return` expression recursively test heights of all subtrees?

Comment: I agree with the position of `*`'s that you mention, specifically because of a confusion I had in the past. Once I wrote something like `int* x, y, z`, thinking that they would all be pointers, because of the way I wrote my `*`'s, but if you write that instead as `int *x, y, z` then it makes it a lot clearer what's going on.

Comment: @ZarakshR I was blibd. I didn't notice the recursive calls. Edited. As a side note, you'd be in better shape to return both a boolean state, _and_ a height, cutting a run time  by a factor of 2.

Comment: @vnp Not sure what you mean by returning a height....

Answer (score 5):

I would be a little more careful and consistent with my styling. You have

```c
if (curDepth == maxDepth) {return NULL;}
```

but you later have

```c
if (!tree) { return true; }
```

Similarly, I would recommend placing spaces between arithmetic operators, `a + b` rather than `a+b`. If you don't want to do this, at least be consistent with it.

For values which refer to the size of something, you should use `size_t` instead of `int`, considering `<stdlib.h>` is already included. If you really can't use a `size_t`, you should keep everything unsigned (does a negative size make sense?).

`if (!tree)` doesn't read to me as "check for a null tree". I would recommend  replacing it with the negligibly more verbose, but clearer `if (tree == NULL)`.

As was said before, the result of `malloc` should not be casted. I also agree with the stylistic choice of the `*` in pointers being put to the left of the variable name.

`heightDiff * -1` can be replaced by `-heightDiff` to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 3):

**Inefficient**

`isAVLBalanced()` makes far too many excursions through the tree to report a boolean answer.  It looks O(n*n).

Note: [AVL balanced tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Balance_factor)

Instead walk the tree, at most, once, looking for imbalances along the way: O(n).  Something like below.  Since the tree does not change, use `const`.

```
// Return the height of the tree if sub-trees still nearly balanced.  
// Otherwise return SIZE_MAX.
size_t Btree_HeightWithBFTest(const BTree *tree) {
  if (tree == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }
  size_t height_left = Btree_HeightWithBFTest(tree->left);
  if (height_left == SIZE_MAX) {
    return SIZE_MAX;
  }
  size_t height_right = Btree_HeightWithBFTest(tree->right);
  if (height_right == SIZE_MAX) {
    return SIZE_MAX;
  }
  if (height_left > height_right) {
    if (height_left - height_right > 1) {
      return SIZE_MAX;
    }
    return height_left + 1;
  }
  if (height_right - height_left > 1) {
    return SIZE_MAX;
  }
  return height_right + 1;
}

bool isAVLBalanced(const BTree *tree) {
   size_t height = Btree_HeightWithBFTest(tree);
   return height != SIZE_MAX;
}
```

**Simplify**

```
// int heightDiffAbs = heightDiff < 0 ? heightDiff * -1 : heightDiff;
int heightDiffAbs = abs(heightDiff);
```

**Robust code would check for allocation success**

**Embedded functions not allowed**

As partly mentioned by others, "warning: ISO C forbids nested functions"

Make `_genRandomTree()` and `int _height()` `static` helper functions.  Avoid the leading `_`.

**Improve style**

Use an auto formatter on the code.  Saves times and improves uniformity of code's appearance.

**Why `-Wc++-compat`?**

Unfortunately this tends to make C code less C like.  Consider dropping it unless you have a compelling reason for it.